# aggregate function can`t work in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, aggregate-functions

I want to use aggregate function on mysql. I have to use this query.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM \`pelayanan\` where \`ID_STATUS\` = '1'
```

But, It doesn`t work. It became error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) FROM `pelayanan` where `ID_STATUS` = '1' LIMIT 0, 25' at
>   line 1

It same error for the other aggregate function like sum.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM pelayanan 
where ID_STATUS = '1';
```

A space is not allowed after any function, including `count()`. So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM pelayanan 
WHERE ID_STATUS = '1';
```

This is explained in a note in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions.html):

> Note
>
> By default, there must be no whitespace between a function name and
> the parenthesis following it. This helps the MySQL parser distinguish
> between function calls and references to tables or columns that happen
> to have the same name as a function. However, spaces around function
> arguments are permitted.